# ndnSIM: hijacker doesn't work and empty PIT

Tags: c++, ns-3

I'm working on a simple tree topology. I want that one specific node (a router) works like an hijacker, so I tried to set this node to Hijacker but this node works like a normal node and forward everything to the correct destination.

Furthermore I can't fill the PITs of every node of the topology, if I try to simulate the application, every PIT is empty, but with the visualizer I can see that every packet pass toward every node.

This is my code:

```
// Install CCNx stack on all nodes
    ndn::StackHelper ccnxHelper;
    ccnxHelper.SetForwardingStrategy ("ns3::ndn::fw::BestRoute");  
    ccnxHelper.SetPit ("ns3::ndn::pit::SerializedSize", "MaxSize", "100");
    ccnxHelper.SetContentStore ("ns3::ndn::cs::Lru", "MaxSize", "1");   // Content Store OFF
    ccnxHelper.InstallAll ();

    // Installing global routing interface on all nodes
    ndn::GlobalRoutingHelper ccnxGlobalRoutingHelper;
    ccnxGlobalRoutingHelper.InstallAll ();

    // Getting containers for the consumer/producer
    Ptr<Node> consumer1 = Names::Find<Node> ("leaf-1");
    Ptr<Node> consumer2 = Names::Find<Node> ("leaf-2");
    Ptr<Node> consumer4 = Names::Find<Node> ("leaf-4");
    Ptr<Node> producer = Names::Find<Node> ("leaf-3");
    Ptr<Node> router3 = Names::Find<Node> ("rtr-3");
    Ptr<Node> router2 = Names::Find<Node> ("rtr-2");
    Ptr<Node> router1 = Names::Find<Node> ("rtr-1");


    //consumerswindow
    ndn::AppHelper consumerHelper ("ns3::ndn::ConsumerWindow");
    consumerHelper.SetAttribute ("Window", UintegerValue (100)); 
    consumerHelper.SetAttribute ("Size", StringValue("0.1"));   
    consumerHelper.SetPrefix ("/rtr-3/leaf-3");
    consumerHelper.Install (consumer1);
    consumerHelper.SetPrefix ("/rtr-3/leaf-3");
    consumerHelper.Install (consumer2);

   //hijaker router1
   ndn::AppHelper hijackerHelper ("Hijacker");
   hijackerHelper.Install (router1);

   //attacker consumercbr
   ndn::AppHelper consumerHelper_attack ("ns3::ndn::ConsumerCbr");
   consumerHelper_attack.SetAttribute ("Frequency", StringValue ("1")); 
   consumerHelper_attack.SetPrefix ("/rtr-3/leaf-3");
   consumerHelper_attack.Install (consumer4);


   //producer leaf-3
   ndn::AppHelper producerHelper ("ns3::ndn::Producer");
   producerHelper.SetAttribute ("PayloadSize", StringValue("1024")); 

   ccnxGlobalRoutingHelper.AddOrigins ("/rtr-3", producer);
   producerHelper.SetPrefix ("/rtr-3");
   producerHelper.Install (producer);

   // Calculate and install FIBs
   ccnxGlobalRoutingHelper.CalculateRoutes ();

   Simulator::Schedule (Seconds (1.0), printPitStats, router1); //print statistics about PIT
   Simulator::Stop (Seconds (5.0));
   Simulator::Run ();
   Simulator::Destroy ();
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conversation has moved to the [ndnSIM](http://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/pipermail/ndnsim/2013-December/000980.html) email list.